# Spreadsheet XML creating a parent/child hierarchy in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following spreadsheet XML:

```
<Workbook>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Parent</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Child</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">D</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">E</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">F</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">C</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">G</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I'm looking to transform it using Saxon XSLT 2.0 into the following format:

```
<Something id="A">
    <Something id="B">
        <Something id="D"/>
        <Something id="E"/>
    </Something>
    <Something id="C">
        <Something id="F"/>
        <Something id="G"/>
    </Something>
</Something>
```

Is anyone able to help with this? I believe the answer lies in a recursive **apply-templates** (although I expect a for-each may achieve the same thing).

Many thanks.

Update: In response to Navin, I have been trying XSLT which looks like the following, but I fear I'm barking up the wrong tree (perhaps in my group-starting-with?):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    exclude-result-prefixes="o x ss html"
    >   

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Workbook/Worksheet[@ss:Name='Sheet1']/Table">      
        <xsl:variable name="row_header" select="count(Row/Cell[.='Parent']/preceding-sibling::Row)+1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[position() > $row_header]">
            <xsl:with-param name="row_header" select="$row_header"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:param name="row_header"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ChildId" select="Cell[count(ancestor::*/Row[$row_header]/Cell[.='Child']/preceding-sibling::Cell)+1]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ParentId" select="Cell[count(ancestor::*/Row[$row_header]/Cell[.='Parent']/preceding-sibling::Cell)+1]"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Row">
            <Something id="{$ChildId}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() &gt; 1]" mode="Child">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ChildId" select="$ChildId"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </Something>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="Child">
        <xsl:param name="ChildId"/>
            <Something id="{$ChildId}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks Navin: have updated my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following xslt will do. (Only tried with xlt version 1.0  and there are some issues with mamesppace.) It is not really flexible it assumes that the first row is the header, the first cell is the parent and the second is the child.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ss="Sheet1"
                >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name ="parent">
            <xsl:value-of select="//Row[2]/Cell[1]/Data"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Something id="{$parent}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row[Cell[position()=1 and Data=$parent]]" />
        </Something>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">

        <xsl:variable name ="child">
            <xsl:value-of select="Cell[2]/Data"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <Something id="{$child}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row[Cell[position()=1 and Data=$child]]" />
        </Something>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:styles
```

The generated output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Something xmlns:ss="Sheet1" id="A">
  <Something id="B">
    <Something id="D"/>
    <Something id="E"/>
  </Something>
  <Something id="C">
    <Something id="F"/>
    <Something id="G"/>
  </Something>
</Something>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, nice and simple and it worked for my purposes. Could you explain how the XPATH works in the apply-templates?

Comment: In human language it is like: select all(//) Row which have a first Cell (positton()=1) which has Data with value equal to parent/child.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better XSLT 2.0 approach, but here's how it can be done in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="Row" use="Cell[2]/Data"/>
  <xsl:key name="kParent" match="Row" use="Cell[1]/Data "/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="*/*/*/*[position() != 1]
                            [not(key('kChildren', Cell[1]/Data))]
                            [generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kParent', Cell[1]/Data)[1])]">
      <xsl:with-param name="idCell" select="1" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:param name="idCell" select="2" />
    <Something id="{Cell[$idCell]/Data}">
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="key('kParent', Cell[$idCell]/Data)
                      [generate-id() = 
                       generate-id(key('kChildren', Cell[2]/Data)[1])]" />
    </Something>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Something id="A">
  <Something id="B">
    <Something id="D" />
    <Something id="E" />
  </Something>
  <Something id="C">
    <Something id="F" />
    <Something id="G" />
  </Something>
</Something>
```